# What's the difference between () and [] in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

```
x <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
```

What are the outcomes of the following,

```
sum(x>5) 
sum(x[x>5])
```

Could anyone tell me what it exactly it means, I'm new to R Programming.

Comment: I should think you can find the outcomes very easily

Comment: also should be `sum` not `Sum`

Comment: @moman822 Thanks it was code edited but doesn't answer or help in anyway, could you please elaborate

Comment: [] is to index. sum(x > 5) means to add up the vector or elements inside (), which are (FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE), and R understands TRUE as 1, and FALSE as 0. So the result is 3. However, x[x>5] means to 'find' among x vector that are of "TRUE", which is in fact: x[FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE]. Since [] works as indexing, it only gets us the elements that are TRUE, and erase FALSE's. So it's to sum up elements in x that are TRUE; 6,8,10. so it becomes 24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x>5` returns `FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE` the sum of which is 3 because of the 3 `TRUE`s. It is telling you whether the condition is met for each value of x (`x[i]>5`?) and summing the responses.

`x[x>5]` subsets `x` for each value that is greater than 5, returning 6, 8 and 10, the sum of which is 24.

Answer (score 2):

`[` is used to subset values from an object based on a vector. There are different rules which depend on the type of object you are subsetting.

`(` is used to specify parameters which will be passed to a function. In your case, a sum.

See `?"("` for more on braces.

Your first statement will test each element in x and return if it's true or not. This will be coerced to 1 and 0, respectively and summed up (0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 3).

The second statement will subset only elements bigger than 5 (6 + 8 + 10 = 24) and sum them up.

Comment: Of course `(` can also be used as a function on its own too (just returning its argument), like `((function(x,y) invisible(x + y))(1, 2))`.